# mysql update move duplicates to a different column

Tags: mysql

I have a table `contacts` that contains columns `index_id`,`name`,`address`,`phone1`,`phone2`,`phone3`.

Due to poor management over the years, there are 212,019 rows out of 484,097 where `phone1` is not unique.  However, each record is a unique record.

I need `phone1` to be unique, but I don't want to lose 212k records doing it.

`phone3` is a new column that is null for each record.  My thought is I could simply move* `VALUES(phone1)` into `phone3`

I tried this query not understanding that ON DUPLICATE UPDATE would simply update the previously existing record.

```
insert into tmp select * from contacts
on duplicate key update phone3 = values(phone1);
```

I tried just moving* all the duplicates over to phone3 with

```
update contacts 
set phone3 = phone1
where count(phone3) > 1;
```

But that's an invalid use of group function.

I'm thinking this is going to require a subquery, that's where I start to get confused.  Are there any suggestions?

*move is to mean that the data would no longer be in `phone1` but rather would be in `phone3`. as in `phone1 = NULL` and `phone3 = data`

Comment: Why would phone1 be unique?  What about people in the same family (or small office)?  Are you having trouble with duplicate entries or just want to force phone1 to be either unique or null for some reason?  Analysis: `select phone1, group_concat(distinct name), group_concat(distinct address) from contacts group by phone1 having count(*) > 1` what's the sample output?

Comment: Yes, all of our contacts are small office.  This table feeds various marketing tools.  Having the same phone number in phone1 for 10 people means that that same office may be contacted 10 individual times.  Even when the office has been asked to be removed from the contact list.  So, we don't want to lose the data, but we want phone1 to be unique.  I did the same with email1.  But that list of duplicates was so small I just moved them by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will move all duplicated phone1 to column phone3. Phone1 will be set to null for every record where there's a duplicate:

```
UPDATE
  contacts c1 inner join (select phone1
                          from contacts
                          group by phone1
                          having count(*)>1) c2
  on c1.phone1=c2.phone1
SET
  c1.phone1=null, c1.phone3=c1.phone1
```

Comment: `c1.phone1=c2.phone1`?  Also, how does this handle different names with the same phone number?  (possibly also the same address)

Comment: @ebyrob thanks, i misspelled phone1, now it's okay! this query does not handle different names with the same phone number, i could add one more coulmn on the subquery and on the on condition, but i think this is what the OP wants...

Comment: I need to verify the data before I can accept the answer, but after a test run on my dev db... fthiella's query seems to do the job, and quickly as well.